# Best way to escape special characters in NSString used in a network protocol

Tags: objective-c

I am building up a string in a network protocol and I would like to escape special characters in the key-value pair I am transmitting.  What's the best approach?

For example, in URL escaping scheme, a space is replaced with %20.

So two questions to this:

1) What is the most appropriate escape scheme (e.g. url escape)

2) How to perform the actual escape? (e.g. stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding if url escape is the best scheme)

e.g.

```
metadata:key1=value1;key2=value2
```

In this case we want to escape equal sign, colon and semicolon that will appear in key or value.

Comment: How do you want to escape it?

Comment: For example, in URL you escape by replacing a space with %20.

Comment: there you replace what you want to replace here and with what?

Comment: That's what my question - what's the appropriate replacement scheme (e.g. url escape scheme) and how.

Comment: Darn downvote troll is in action again.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove all : ; = then you can use:

```
NSCharacterSet *yourCharacterSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@";:="];
NSString *escapedString = [initialString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:yourCharacterSet];
```

Comment: I am sorry my question wasn't clear.  I have edited it with more info.

Answer (score 0):

As you build up the string, you'll have to adjust each key & value separately.

e.g.

```
NSMutableString *xmitText = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:100];

// for each key/value pair:
{
  NSString *key = ...
  key = [key stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"\\="];
  key = [key stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@"\\:"];
  key = [key stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@"\\;"];

  // Same for value
  ...
  [xmitText appendFormat:@"%@=%@;", key, value];
}
```